# Spring Batch: Working with several entities and merge them

Tags: spring-batch

I need to denormalize data stored into a relational database.

There are too much tables linked between each others, and it's not possible to build a single query to get every data.

Here a simplified situation:

```
+-------------+           +-------------+
|             | 1       N |             |
|   Unitat    +----------->   Authors   |
|             |           |             |
+-------------+           +-------------+
```

Up to now I've build an step that is getting all `Unitat` rows:

```java
@Bean
public ItemReader<Unitat> reader() {
    String sql = "select * from unitat";

    JdbcCursorItemReader<Unitat> jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(sql);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new UnitatRowMapper());

    return jdbcCursorItemReader;
}
```

The `RowMapper` is:

```java
public class UnitatRowMapper implements RowMapper<Unitat> {

    private static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
    //...

    @Override
    public Unitat mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int numRow) throws SQLException {
        Unitat unitat = new Unitat();

        unitat.setId(resultSet.getString(ID_COLUMN));
        //...

        return unitat;
    }

}
```

Here my processor. It's only engaged to populate fields into a `UnitatDenormalized` object:

```java
@Component
public class UnitatMappingItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Unitat, UnitatDenormalized> {

    @Override
    public UnitatDenormalized process(Unitat unitat) throws Exception {
        UnitatDenormalized denormalized = new UnitatDenormalized();

        denormalized.setId(unitat.getId());
        //denormalized.set...()

        return denormalized;
    }

}
```

Here my current step and job configuration:

```java
@Bean
public Step step(
    ItemReader<Unitat> mssqlItemReader,
    UnitatMappingItemProcessor processor,
    SolrItemWriter solrItemWriter
) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
        .get("unitat")
        .<Unitat, UnitatDenormalized>chunk(100)
        .reader(mssqlItemReader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(solrItemWriter)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Job job(Step step) {
    Job job = this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
        .flow(step)
        .end()
        .build();
    return job;
}
```

How could I get authors and merge them to previously obtained `unitat`?

When and how could I perform next code?

```java
// Here would I need to populate `authors`:
denormalized.addAutors(...);
denormalized.addAutors(...);
```

I hope I've explained so well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). The idea is to issue a request in your item processor to enrich items.

In your case, the query would fetch authors of the current `unitat` item and set them on the `denormalized` item before returning it.